# Does TFS have a way to indicate that I gotten an old version of a file?

Tags: tfs

Does TFS have a way to indicate that I have gotten an old version of a file?

I have previously used Accurev which will put the old version in your default group.  So I'm wondering if TFS shows this information somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in Source Control Explorer, there is a column called "Latest". It would show Yes, if you have the latest file and No" if you don't have the latest version.

Please be mindful it doesn't scan your file contents to see if you have the latest. For example, if you have manually updated the file in your local drive without using TFS, the latest column will still show the status it was in before.

Comment: which is pretty rubbish - it shows you have the latest version, except sometimes when you don't. How useful is that :( All the TortoiseXXX products can do this, beats me why Microsoft can''t.

Comment: Thanks for the answer although I'll admit I was hoping there was a way to get a list of files I made old on purpose.